# How is CAST(VARBINARY AS NVARCHAR) implemented in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, casting

I'm specifically referring to how stored procedure input parameters are handled. Does it just change how SQL Server interprets the data, or does it require SQL Server to make a copy of the data?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is text, why is it stored as VARBINARY?

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928600/efficiently-adding-large-amounts-of-text-to-a-database/1931650#1931650

Answer (score 1):

Each `NVARCHAR` character occupies `2` bytes, so `SQL Server` will pad `NVARCHAR` size to the nearest larger even integer:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST('qqq' AS VARBINARY) vb
        )
SELECT  DATALENGTH(CAST(vb AS NVARCHAR(20)))
FROM    q

---
  4
```

What do you mean by "copy of the data"? This depends on the execution plan. `SQL Server` can make a copy of a whole table (say, in an `Eager Spool`) even without type casting.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that I'm specifically referring to stored procedure parameters. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign @variableA to @variableB there has to occur a copy, irelevant of the CAST.

If you use an @variable in a query things are a lot murkier and whether a copy occurs or not depends on the context of the CAST.